# Solr fq parameter over an array of objects

Tags: solr

I am currently trying to query over the following data structure:

```
'id': 'test',
"user": 'test,
"extras":

[{'paperName' : 'test',
'key': 'key1',
'value': 'value1',},

{'paperName' : 'test2',
'key': 'key2',
'value': 'value2',}]
```

Currently in my fq parameter if I wanted to just wanted to search for a specific user I could just pass ' `id:"test"`' into my fq parameter to filter out the rest. My question is how  would I structure my fq input 
if I wanted to only filter for `key1` with a value of `value1` in the extras object array?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107450/how-to-store-and-retrieve-apache-solr-fields-as-a-tree-multidimensional-array

Comment: Thank you vinod, that is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store and retrieve Apache Solr fields as a tree (multidimensional array)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107450/how-to-store-and-retrieve-apache-solr-fields-as-a-tree-multidimensional-array)