# Deeply nested JSON documents in Apache Solr

Tags: json, apache, solr

I have a deeply nested document(pseudo structure as shown below):

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "company_id": "1",
    "company_name": "company_1",
    "departments":[{
                 "dep1" : [{
                           "id" : 40,
                           "name" : xyz
                           },
                           {
                           "id" : 41,
                           "name" : xyr
                           }],
                "dep2": [{
                }]
            }]
    "employeePrograms" :[{
    }]
}]
```

How can I index these type of documents in Apache Solr?
Documentation gives the idea of immediate child documents alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly i'm don't have huge experience with this technology, but want to help. Here is some official documentation, that might be useful: [oficial doc](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Indexing+and+Basic+Data+Operations)
[more specific](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Introduction+to+Solr+Indexing)

If you have some uncommon issue, tell about it, maybe any error, or whatever.. I would try my best to help)

**Upd1 :** 
Solr can only maintain a 'flat' representation of the data. What you weretrying to do is not really possible. There are a number of workarounds, such as using [dynamic fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370466/solr-index-for-multi-valued-multi-type-field) and using a [solr join](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join) to link multiple data sets.

Speking about a deep  nesting ? I've found such an example of work around. 
If you had something like that:

```
 "docs": [
      {
        "name": "Product Name",
        "categories": [
          {
            "name": "Category 1",
            "priority": 8
          },
          {
            "name": "Category 2",
            "priority": 6
          }
          ...
        ]
      },
```

You have to modify it like that to make it not deeply nested :

```
 "docs": [
    {
      name: "Sample Product"
      categories: [
      {
        priority_category: "9_Category 1",
      },
      {
        priority_category: "5_Category 2",
      }
      ...
      ]
    },
```

So, you've done something similar, check if there are any errors anywhere

Comment: Thanks @Altenrion. Really appreciate your help.                   Documentation gives the idea of one level of child documents alone. But I have multiple levels of child documents. Please refer the psuedo structure in my question.

Comment: I indexed the nested doc's successfully in Solr.[{
    "id": "1",
    "company_id": "1",
    "company_name": "company_1",
 "content_type":"parentDocument",
    "_childDocuments_":[{
              "content_type":"dep",
                 "_childDocuments_" : [{
                           "id" : 40,
                           "dep_name" : xyz
                           },
                           {
                           "id" : 41,
                           "dep_name" : xyr
                           },
         {
         "id" : 22,
         "emp_program": zzz
         }]
            }]
}]

Comment: When i want to get back the doc's(parent and child documents as a single document), I get the parent and the respective child doc;s using the  query. **q={!parent which=content_type:parentDocument}&fl=[child parentFilter=content_type:parentDocument]**. But the document nested structure is lost. I get only the flat list of child documents(Even the grandchildren of a parent are given as child of a parent). Please let me know how can i get or form the nested structure of the document in the results?

Comment: I have updated the answer, instead of writing the new one.  let me know if it is helpful or not

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot flatten the document.Maybe Solr is not suitable for my use-case(deeply nested JSON documents). I found Elasticsearch inherently supports deeply nested structures and fits for my use-case. Anyway thanks for the help.